# Unable to build an Ionic/Angular app after packages upgrade

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've upgraded Ionic and angular packages to the latest version and unable to run `ionic build`

my dependencies are:

```
 "@angular/core": "~10.1.4",
 "ionic-angular": "^3.9.10",
```

And the error I'm getting when trying to build is below:

```
node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/item/item-divider.d.ts:1:22 - error TS2724: Module '"../../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer'. Did you mean 'Renderer2'?

1 import { ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
                       ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5964:31
    5964 export declare abstract class Renderer2 {
                                       ~~~~~~~~~
    'Renderer2' is declared here.
```

Please advise how to make the `ionic-angular` dependency work.

Comment: `import {  ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';` in angular 10 Renderer is updated to Renderer2.

Comment: https://v9.angular.io/guide/migration-renderer

Comment: the ionic-angular package is a 3d party official package, I cannot just import another renderer. It sounds like the package I upgraded to is no longer compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages `@angular/core` and `ionic-angular` are incompatible and upgrading angular to v10 forces to use `@ionic/angular` package instead:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/migration#changes-in-package-name

Answer (score 0):

Try to import Renderer2 instead of Renderer.

Comment: that's not possible, I don't own both packages, these are 3d party packages.